# System.Action and non-static variables

Tags: c#, events, delegates

This is probably a duplicate, but I cannot find any threads which explain this behavior. At least not pertaining to `Action` (which are basically Func's with no return type). It's to do with static references.

Look at these two examples. I'm merely trying to subscribe to the `System.Action OnButton1Down`, to make it call a non-static function when the `Action` is invoked with `.Invoke()`.

Why does the first method work, but not the second or third ones? I would much rather have the `Action` saved/prepared, so I can also unsubscribe it again without trickery, by simply doing: OnButton1Down -=

```
System.Action OnButton1Down;

void MyNonStaticFunction() { }

// This example works
void MyFirstFunction()
{
    OnButton1Down += () => { MyNonStaticFunction(); };
}


// This example gives the following error on "MyNonStaticFunction()":
// "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method
// or property MyNonStaticFunction()."
System.Action MyAction = () => { MyNonStaticFunction(); };

void MySecondStartFunction()
{
    OnButton1Down += MyAction;
}

// This example is to show what happens, if I just try to subscribe the raw
// method to the Action, as suggested in the comments.
// It gives the following error on "MyNonStaticFunction()":
// "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to type 'System.Action'."
void MyThirdStartFunction()
{
    OnButton1Down += MyNonStaticFunction();
}
```

I sort of understand that the errors make sense, but I don't see why the first example is OK. I would much rather be able to do either of the other examples.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as image. It allows us to copy/paste it into Visual Studio and to try to reproduce the problem and try solutions.

Comment: Why are you not simply writing `_playerInput.OnButton1Down += MyNonStaticFunction;`? How is `OnButton1Down` delcared/typed?

Comment: im pretty sure they plan to allow this in C#8 mentioned here :https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/01/20/new-features-in-c-sharp-7/ ... FYI

Comment: Added more explanation, text-code etc.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your second issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't allow you to access any instance members before the object is fully constructed (i.e. all field initializers have run).

To get around this you can initialize `MyAction` in the class constructor, which will run after all the field initializers.

Edit: To reply to the second part of your question:

```
OnButton1Down += MyNonStaticFunction();
```

You're calling `MyNonStaticFunction`, not converting it to a delegate! Remove the `()` and it'll work better!

Comment: Thank you! This was the missing piece. I can simply assign my non-static method to the temporary action variable in the constructor. Perfect!